# LakeFS, S3 Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, aws-data-wrangler, lakefs

I am trying to write parquet files to LakeFS with S3 configuration. I configured docker for my services.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
      - redis_db
      - laksefs
    env_file:
      - path: .env
        required: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: "redis_db"

  redis_db:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}

  laksefs:
    image: treeverse/lakefs:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment:
      LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_TYPE: "s3"
      LAKEFS_LOGGING_FORMAT: "text"
      LAKEFS_LOGGING_LEVEL: "TRACE"
      LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_FORCE_PATH_STYLE: true
      LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      LAKEFS_BLOCKSTORE_S3_REGION: "us-east-2"
      LAKEFS_AUTH_ENCRYPT_SECRET_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      LAKEFS_DATABASE_TYPE: ${LAKEFS_DATABASE_TYPE}
      LAKEFS_DATABASE_POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING: "host=postgres_db user=${POSTGRES_USER} password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} dbname=${POSTGRES_DB} sslmode=disable"
      LAKEFS_INSTALLATION_USER_NAME: "admin"
      LAKEFS_INSTALLATION_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${LAKEFS_ACCESS_KEY}
      LAKEFS_INSTALLATION_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${LAKEFS_SECRET_KEY}
      LAKEFS_GATEWAYS_S3_REGION: "us-east-2"
      LAKECTL_SERVER_ENDPOINT_URL: "http://localhost:8000"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

I tried with multiple variations but it is not working. I am getting the error:
[image]

I checked the Endpoint, LakeFS Access Key, and Secret, All are correctly configured.

I am using AWS Wrangler to write the data to lakeFS.

wr.config.s3_endpoint_url = lfs_endpoint

```
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: wr.s3.to_parquet(
        df=batch.to_pandas() ,
        path=lfs_s3_path,
        dataset=True,
        max_rows_by_file=max_rows_per_file,
        use_threads=True,
        partition_cols = partitioning,
        mode='append',
        boto3_session=s3_session
    ))
```

What could go wrong here?

When I am running without docker, it works fine